# Devise model with CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Problem: when I `create.save` guest, error appears `ActionController::UnknownFormat in GuestsController#create`, through the record is saved. Any Ideas how to get rid of it?

I have:

- `rails g devise guest` ;
- `rails g controller guests` for CRUD interface.

guests_controller.rb:

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_guest, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @guest = Guest.new
  end
  def edit
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
      if @guest.save
        redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully created.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    #update without changing password
    if params[:guest][:password].blank?
      params[:guest].delete(:password)
      params[:guest].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    #usual actions
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    if @guest.update_attributes(guest_params)
      sign_in(@guest, :bypass => true) if @guest == current_guest
      redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def set_guest
      @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    end
    def guest_params
      params.require(:guest).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Maybe some redirect in registrations/controller?...

I tried routes `devise_for :guests, controllers: { registrations: 'guest_registrations' }` + `guest_registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class GuestRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(guest)
    guests_path # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end
end
```

but it did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `respond_to` but you are not telling the response format

Try this instead:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
        if @guest.save
          redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully created.'
        else
          render :new
        end
      end
    end
end
```

A response format can be `:json, :html, :xml, :js`.

More better version than above:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
         @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
         if @guest.save
           format.html { redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully created' }
           format.json {render json: @guest}
         else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @guest.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request }
         end
     end
end
```

Comment: It worked :) I guess I have to add the same to  `update` action. Thanks, Rahul

Comment: yes if you are going to handle multiple reponse format.